# How to get access to files in a crashed ubuntu operating system?

Tags: ubuntu

I had dual boot(Window/Ubuntu) system. Ubuntu System got crashed. While booting Ubuntu System, message appeared on screen was "Errors were found while checking the disk drive for /".So, in order to backup data I tried to access files using bootable Ubuntu USB. But to all files in home folder this message appears "You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of "XYZFolder"".

Answer (score 0):

Use sudo or log into your Ubunto USB system as root. you should then be able to read the files, change their ownership etc etc

Comment: That means anyone can access Users private data using a USB bootable Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes - I think it does, unless you're using some form of full-disk encryption.